# Limiting bandwith usage of a python process while downloading data

Tags: python, networking, bandwidth

I have created a python client which creates multiple sockets to upload/download files from a server.
I noticed mulitple times that when downloading too much data at once, my router restarted and my internet was offline for about 3 minutes. I have read that this happens when the bandwidth limit is exceded. How can I set a bandwidth limit for all the sockets open at the time?

I could find this: https://pypi.org/project/aiothrottle/
But when using this module I can't use my sockets module anymore and need to use aiohttp which should mean to me to recreate my hole python client.

```
# simplified version of my code #

import socket
ip = "1.1.1.1"
port = 8080

def start():
        mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            mysocket.connect((ip, port))
            mysocket.send(str.encode("GET " + "Data" + "HTTP/1.1 \r\n"))
            mysocket.sendto(str.encode("GET " + "Data" + "HTTP/1.1 \r\n"), (ip, port))
        except socket.error:
            print("e")
        mysocket.close()


while i in range(4): # here I am creating multiple sockets to upload/download data from different hosts
    t = Thread(target=start)
    t.start()
```

How to change the code so that none of the threads, containing a socket, will exceed a bandwidth limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just can set max speed for transfer and interval for check how much bytes thread download while this time.

```py
interval = 1.0 #seconds
max_bandwidth = 50 * 1024 #kilobytes * 1024
```

Then use socket.recv for downloading chunks in loop and create temporary control variable for measure how much data thread downloaded in interval. If downloaded data amount is bigger than max_bandwidth * interval then sleep thread for interval value. Similar method use for sending.